# Error with the structure of array passed as argument for joint diagonalisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use `ffdiag` ([pybss](https://github.com/archimonde1308/pybss)) from the following function :

```
def ffdiag(X, max_lag = 10, eps = 1.0e-10, max_iter = 100):
    '''
    Blind source separation using FFDIAG.  This version does not require that
    the estimated mixing matrix be orthogonal.

    INPUT:
    ------
    X : array, required
        N_sig x t matrix of signal mixtures

    max_lag : int, optional
        maximum lag (in samples) for covariance matrix calculation

    eps : double, optional
        convergence criterion for matrix updates

    max_iter : int, optional
        maximum number of iterations/updates
    '''
    R_tau = linalg.lagged_covariance(X,max_lag)
    dim = len(R_tau[0])
    n_lags = len(R_tau.keys())
    W = zeros((dim,dim))
    V = eye(dim)
    C = R_tau
    niter = 0
    theta = 0.9
    iter_eps = 1.0
```

with `lagged_covariance` defined by :

```
def lagged_covariance(X, max_lag):
    '''
    Generates a dictionary of lagged covariance matrices of matrix X, for
    lags 0,1,2,...,max_lag.

    INPUT:
    ------
    X : array, required
        N x t data matrix

    max_lag : integer, required
        covariance matrices will be computed for lags 0,1,...,max_lag

    OUTPUT:
    ------
    R_tau : dictionary, keyed on the lag, with values equal to the lagged
        covariance of X with the lagged version of itself.
    '''
    R_tau = {}
    t = X.shape[1]
    dim = X.shape[0]
    R_tau[0] = cov(X,X)[0:dim,dim::]
    for tau in range(1,max_lag+1):
        for i in range(tau,t):
            # create X(t) and X(t-tau)
            X_t = X[:,0:t-tau]
```

I get the following error :

```
/Users/henry/pybss/linalg.py", line 92, in lagged_covariance
    R_tau[0] = cov(X,X)[0:dim,dim::]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in cov
  File "/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2371, in cov
    raise ValueError("m has more than 2 dimensions")
ValueError: m has more than 2 dimensions
```

In my script, I am calling `ffdiag` like this :

```
# dimension
m=7
# number of matrices
n=2

# Load spectro and WL+GCph+XC
FISH_GCsp = np.loadtxt('Fisher_GCsp_flat.txt')
FISH_XC = np.loadtxt('Fisher_XC_GCph_WL_flat.txt')

# Marginalizing over uncommon parameters between the two matrices
COV_GCsp_first = np.linalg.inv(FISH_GCsp)
COV_XC_first = np.linalg.inv(FISH_XC)
COV_GCsp = COV_GCsp_first[0:m,0:m]
COV_XC = COV_XC_first[0:m,0:m]
# Invert to get Fisher matrix
FISH_sp = np.linalg.inv(COV_GCsp)
FISH_xc = np.linalg.inv(COV_XC)
# Drawing a random set of commuting matrices
C=np.zeros((n,m,m));
B=np.zeros((n,m,m));
C[0,:,:] = np.array(FISH_sp)
C[1,:,:] = np.array(FISH_xc)

[invV, B, ut] = ffdiag(C, 10, 1.0e-10, 100)
```

but I don't know if the array `C` is well defined : in any cases, I have got to pass 2 matrices of size 7x7 but in which order :

```
# dimension
m=7
# number of matrices
n=2

C=np.zeros((n,m,m));
B=np.zeros((n,m,m));
```

or

```
C=np.zeros((m,m,n));
B=np.zeros((m,m,n));
```

or something else since the both above don't seem to work.

As you can see in the definition of ffdiag, it is noticed :

```
INPUT:
        ------
        X : array, required
            N_sig x t matrix of signal mixtures
```

But I can't guess which is the structure of `X array`.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: In particular, your questions have "any help is welcome" in various permutations, despite this having now been edited from ~40+ of them. Volunteers wanting to encourage technical writing are already stretched too thinly, and thousands of people a day come in wanting to use Stack Overflow as a chatroom. Have mercy on us!